# How to change header template in extjs 4 grid panel

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I want to change default header template of grid. I do not know what config or property to set. I tried "renderTpl" , "tpl" , "metaRowTpl" but these property related to row in grid, where i want to change header.

[image: headerView]

Any example or link would be great.

Like above image, I want extra header/row/column-header in between where text will come from database (and basically it is filter information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the header text with the following command

```
yourGrid.getView().getHeaderAtIndex(columnIndex).setText('Header Text');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alexrom7/YNTuN/3/

Comment: sorry to confuse you. I want to add extra column row inbetween, but i will set its header text in renderer. Any idea how to add extra row in between?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your problem. The "column row" part is what makes me confuse. So I'll try to answer if your case is that you want to add a new column between Column One and Column Two. In that case, you will need to create a Columns array with the order of the columns you want, and then call the reconfigure method of the Grid. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure. The column renderer only affects the content (rows) of that column.

Comment: I want extra row in between column headings and actual content. i.e. inject a row while rendering header template.